# docusign api - automatic hand writed signature

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a possibility with help of API to send envelope without tamplate, that will allow only a hand writed signature in document. It's important that after the first signing, this signature will automatically substitute to next sign places after click.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. The Sign in Each Location feature is very simple to explain. If you enable it for a specific signer, that signer will have to draw their signature for each and every signing element (either signature tabs or initial tabs). Drawing the signature using a mouse may not be ideal, so using a phone or a tablet is recommended (especially if you know your signer has a stylus for their device).

Here you will find code snippets to do this in 6 langs:

https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-sign-each-location

Comment: I want after the first signing, this signature will automatically substitute to next sign places after click.

Comment: Then you have to use regular signature, but you can't force user to sign by hand. Either this or they have to sign by hand everywhere

Answer (score 0):

@Inbar,

How can a DocuSign admin enable this on the DocuSign web application?
I created a fresh trial account.  I went to Signing Settings and I can't find it.

PS: It seems on the web app the feature got renamed to "Required Recipients to Draw Each Signature"

https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301=&bundleId=gav1643676262430&topicId=jyu1578456488969.html&_LANG=enus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA60b.png)